# Adding django autocomplete to tags field

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to add django-autocomplete to the tags field but it doesn't work. I've looked at how to add it  and it includes making a autocomplete file.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(BaseItemModel):
    area = TreeForeignKey(Area, blank=True, null=True,)
    categories = TreeManyToManyField(Category)
    #imdb_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Used only for Series and Movie Reviews")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Movie, blank=True, verbose_name='Parent Movie', null=True, help_text="Used only for Series and Movie Reviews")
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    editor_pick = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)
    html = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,)
    #html_edited = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,)


class ArticleAdmin(CommonAdmin):
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Article)
    list_display = [
        'name',
        'categories_display',
        'modified_by',
        'created_by',
        'modified',
        'created',
        'visible',
        'editor_pick',
        'rating',
        'tags',
    ]
    list_filter = ['modified', 'created', 'visible','editor_pick']
    list_editable = ['visible','editor_pick']
    #filter_horizontal = ('tags',)
    #list_filter = ('categories',)
    excludes = ['sortorder',]
    inlines = [
        HotItemInline,
        ArticleImageInline,
        ArticleYoutubeVideoInline,
        #RelatedArticleInline
    ]

import autocomplete_light

from articles.models import *

autocomplete_light.register(Article, search_fields=('name','tags'),
    autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder': 'article name ..'})
```

it doesn't work for the tags field I'm using autocomplete version 2.0.2

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is it that when you save the model it doesn't do what it supposed to do?

Comment: There's supposed to be an autocomplete and a box to type in when autocomplete overides the  default manytomany display that looks like a multiple select box

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered an autocomplete for Tag: http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/autocomplete.html